# The type or namespace name 'Id' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CosmosDBOutput Problem

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-http-trigger

So the problem that I am encoutring is that I can't use "ID" again, it keeps giving me error for my CosmosDBOutput, I'm not sure why that is but I need help with this if anyone can help fix it.

Here is the Code i have so far and I am using .Net 6 LTS using C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class GetResumeCounter
    {
        [FunctionName("GetResumeCounter")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDBInput(databaseName:"AzureResume", containerName: "Counter", Connection = "AzureResumeConnectionString", Id = "1", PartitionKey = "1")] Counter counter,
            [CosmosDBOutput(databaseName:"AzureResume", containerName: "Counter", Connection = "AzureResumeConnectionString", Id = "1", PartitionKey = "1")] out Counter updatedcounter,

            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            updatedcounter = counter;
            updatedcounter.Count += 1;

            var jsonToRetun = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(counter);

            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(jsonToRetun, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it to build using dotnet build but I keep getting the error:
The type or namespace name 'Id' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

for my CosmosDBOutput please help

Comment: The `Id` property doesn't exist for `[CosmosDBOutput]`

Comment: @Faizan Shaikh `[CosmosDBOutput]` doesnot modify data, it overrides data.

Comment: You can use the `CosmosDBOutput`, just remove the `Id` property from the original code and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks @David Makogon

As David Mentioned `Id` property does not exist in `[CosmosDbOutput]`

You can use `CosmosClient` to update the existing data, as  `[CosmosDbOutput]` overrides the data.

This worked for me.

##### My Code :

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace FunctionApp13
{
    public static class Function
    {
        private static readonly string cosmosEndpoint = "https://resumedbcount.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static readonly string cosmosKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private static readonly string databaseName = "Resume";
        private static readonly string containerName = "Counter";

        private static readonly CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosEndpoint, cosmosKey);
        private static readonly Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);


        [FunctionName("Function")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // Get the document by ID
            var counter = await GetCounterById("1", "1");

            if (counter == null)
            {
                counter = new Counter { id = "1", PartitionKey = "1", Count = 0 };
            }

            // Update the document
            counter.Count++;

            // Replace the document in Cosmos DB
            var response = await container.ReplaceItemAsync(counter, counter.id, new PartitionKey(counter.PartitionKey));

            return new OkObjectResult("replaced successfully");
        }

        private static async Task<Counter> GetCounterById(string id, string partitionKey)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await container.ReadItemAsync<Counter>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
                return response.Resource;
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

        public class Counter
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

}
```

##### Before data:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "PartitionKey": "1",
    "Count": 11
}
```

#### `OUTPUT`:

##### After executing function:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "PartitionKey": "1",
    "Count": 12
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: the OP wasn't asking how to do any specific implementation - they only asked why they're getting a namespace error. The question should be closed, as it's essentially a typo / misuse of a property.

Comment: You can use the `CosmosDBOutput`, just remove the `Id` property from the original code and it should work.